# Embed web application as a resource into C++ Qt executable

Tags: c++, html, qt, web-applications, qwebview

I would like to load a sort of "web application" in a `QWebView`.

My "web application" is made up of some HTML5 pages with CSS, Javascript and pictures. It is totally autonomous. It does not need a server.

I am quite new to Qt programming. Is there a way to embed those files into the Qt project and load them in the `QWebView` when the program starts?

I already managed to load those pages from a remote HTTP server but my application must be standalone.

**EDIT**

Thank you for your solution Yodabox. The page is well displayed. I set baseUrl as `"qrc:///web/"` instead of `":/web/"`. But I still have a problem.

I do an async request to an embedded XML file to load values in an HTML select. The JavascriptConsole gives the message: `XHR finished loading: "qrc:///web/xml/values.xml"` **but the select is not populated**. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you Need is  [QWebView::setHtml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml)

```
void QWebView::setHtml ( const QString & html, const QUrl & baseUrl = QUrl() )
```

you should set baseUrl as ":/web/"  and html as the HTML file content,please read Qt DOC for detail.

Answer (score 0):

if those pages aren't suppose to change during the esecution of the application, i think you can encapsulate it in a *resource file*... (i don t know if it is good or bad.. simply it does what you need)

you can read about the resource system here : [Resource System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html)

Comment: Well, I added files into a .qrc file and tried `qWebView->load(QUrl(":/Web/index.html"));` but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: try with *setHtml()* or *setContent()*

Comment: You need to use qWebView->load( QUrl::fromLocalFile( ":/Web/index.html" ) );