# Read local file from QWebView using Ajax request

Tags: c++, ajax, file, qt, qwebview

I am developing a Qt/C++ program which encapsulates an HTML5/JQuery web app.

I used to make Ajax requests to read files from a server. But now, I would like Qt to read a file from the local disk and send its content to my web app.

I think I need Qt to catch Ajax requests from the web app and return the file content as the Ajax request result.

The problem is I don't know how to do. For now, I've not found anything about that on google.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to do it. I overrode `QNetworkAccessManager`.

**MyQNetworkAccessManager .h:**

```
class MyQNetworkAccessManager : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    virtual QNetworkReply * createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0);
};
```

**MyQNetworkAccessManager.cpp:**

```
QNetworkReply * MyQNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData) {
    QUrl url = req.url();
    QString path = url.path();

    if (op == QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation && path.endsWith("xml")) {
        QUrl newUrl;

        if(path.endsWith("..")) {
            newUrl.setUrl("...");
        }
        else if(path.endsWith("...")) {
            newUrl.setUrl("...");
        }
        else {
            newUrl = url;
        }
        return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::GetOperation, QNetworkRequest(newUrl));
    }
    else
    {
        return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, req, outgoingData);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp:**

```
// ....

QWebView *qWebView = new QWebView();

QWebPage *page = qWebView->page();
MyQNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new MyQNetworkAccessManager();
page->setNetworkAccessManager(networkManager);

qWebView->setPage(page);

qWebView->load(QUrl("..."));

// ....
```